# Send a 301 header in a CURL request

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-301

I've googled around for how to send a 301 header with a CURL request in PHP, but have come up with nothing! Does someone know how this can be done? Thanks

Comment: Isn't `301` a *response code*?  What would sending a response code as part of a request look like?

Comment: You don't send "301 headers" in requests at all, so the question is borked to begin with.

Are you asking how to send a 301 in a response or how to make curl act on a 301 response?

Comment: Maybe I phrased the question incorrectly. What I want to achieve is to make a GET request but send a 301 header first before I make the GET request but I don't want to use the traditional *header* function.

Comment: @Newbie That makes no sense - please explain exactly what you are trying to achieve. Who do you want to send the header to - the client who requested your page, or the server you are sending a request to?

Comment: @DaveRandom I wanted to send the header to the client that requested the page. This is in relation to Google bot and making sure Google recognises expired URLs to minimise 404 occurrences. However, I finally managed to achieve this in a simpler fashion by just issuing a 301 with the PHP header function before rendering any page content. Thanks to all for the responses!

Answer (score 3):

301 is not a request  header but a HTTP response status code. As curl is to establish requests - not responses - you can not send a 301 header with curl.